# Как выделить ячейки, которые редактировал пользователь?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Лист спредщита формируется из скрипта. Затем другой пользователь может внести корректировки. Как выделить ячейки в которые были внесены изменения? Например, на подобие условного форматирования? Приветствуются любые идеи.

Comment: Можно сравнить источник и оригинал.

Comment: Я так пока и сделал. А можно как-то через историю версий? Вообще, к истории доступ из GAS есть?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, все еще нет нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать тригер onEdit(), который после изменения ячейки будет подкрашивать/менять шрифт/делать жирным (в общем все, что захочешь). Только нужно будет настроить его работу так, что бы он не срабатывал на формирование листа из скрипта (как вариант добавить значение в скрытую колонку или использовать глобальные переменные).

```
    function onEdit(e){
  let cell = e.range;
if (//тут проверка на то, что это не формирование листа//){
// то, как должна изменяться ячейка//
}
}
```